# Dropbox opens each time I plug in removable media

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, autostart

Every time I plug in removable media Dropbox opens and this window comes up. I only ever want dropbox to open if it's manually started by the user. I have unchecked 'preferences > settings > start with computer' but it still seems to startup for random reasons.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/307

**Disable camera uploads**

> - Click the Dropbox icon in the system tray.
> - Click the gear icon
> - Select Preferences….
> - Click Change AutoPlay Settings from the Camera Upload section.
> - AutoPlay settings will appear in a new window.
>
> To **disable** camera uploads, click the menu next to the camera, phone,
>   or other media device and select Take no action

Answer (score 5):

So this irritated me for a long while and I finally spent the time to figure it out. I went into Control Panel -> autoplay and then found a couple of entries that I changed the default action for:
[control panel->autoplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTSsx.png)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking the "Don't ask again" button in the lower left of your screenshot? FYI, that may be per device. You don't want to disable dropbox starting automatically with Windows or it won't sync your files.